# Bound for exponential

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory

Let $\displaystyle f(x)= e^{-Ae^x} e^{Bx} \left( 1+ \mathcal{O} \left( e^{-x} \right)\right)$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

**Claim:** $|f(x)| = \mathcal{O}\left( \exp(-e^x)\right)$  as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Note that $$\frac{1}{e^{Ae^x}} \leq \frac{e^{Bx}}{e^{Ae^x}} \leq \frac{e^{x}}{e^{Ax}}\leq \frac{1}{(e^x)^{A-1}}$$
hence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{Bx}}{e^{Ae^x}}=0,$$
so $e^{Ae^{x}}$ grows much faster than $e^{Bx}$. Is my argument here correct? I feel like i've done something wrong with my argument or missing something or is my claim even holds? Any comment and help would be so much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is only true if $A > 1$.